# Accumulation Point Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D \subset R$ and let $a \in D$. Show that acc(D \ {a}) = acc(D).

I'm not sure I really understand what this question is asking. How can I show that these accumulation points are equivalent?

Comment: Basically, you need to prove that if $a$ is an accumulation point of $D$, then it's also an accumulation point of $D \setminus \{a\}$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein - not $a$, but any arbitrary accumulation point $x$ of $D$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to show that a point $x$ is an accumulation point of $D$ if and only if $x$ is an accumulation point of $D\setminus\{a\}$.

Proving that accumulation points of $D\setminus\{a\}$ are also accumulation points of $D$ is straightforward.

To prove that if $x$ is an accumulation point of $D$, then it is also an accumulation point of $D\setminus\{a\}$, consider two cases:

- If $x = a$, then note that every neighborhood of $a$ intersects $D$ *in a point other than* $a$.
- If $x \ne a$, then note that any neighborhood of $x$ has a subneighborhood that misses $a$.